# Sql query to return a chain of events

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that tracks changes.  One column is called beforename and the other aftername.

Some sample data might be:

```
BeforeName   AfterName
a            b
b            c
c            d
```

I am trying to write a query that will self reference itself in such a way as to return the changes ie:

a->b->c->d (the arrows are just for notation here)

Is this possible to do in SQL?

My database is Sqlite

TIA

Comment: I am open to schema changes if it will help

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can using recursive CTEs.  Assuming no cycles:

```
with cte as (
      select beforename, aftername as lastone, beforename || '->' || aftername as path, 1 as lev
      from t
      where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.aftername = t.beforename)
      union all
      select cte.beforename, t.aftername as lastone, path || '->' || aftername, lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.lastone = t.beforename
     )
select *
from cte
where lev = (select max(cte2.lev) from cte cte2 where cte2.beforename = ce.beforename);
```

Or, if your version of SQLite supports window functions:

```
select *
from (select cte.*, row_number() over (partition by beforename order by lev desc) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) x
where seqnum = 1;
```